# Linear gradient's bounds computation takes parent's bounds in account, not the node on which it is applied on

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, bounds, linear-gradients, stroke

I want to put a linear gradient on a line(width wise ie across it's stroke width). This line is a child of a Group node. When I apply linear gradient on line, the color stops are calculated using Group's bounds not the lines bounds.
In my code below, linear gradient will show up properly when added length-wise ie "to bottom", but not when added width wise, ie "to right".
Can anyone tell me what can be work around for this?
Here is the SSCCE

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Group group = new Group();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(group, 200, 350));

    Line line = new Line(100, 50, 100, 300);
    group.getChildren().add(line);
    line.setStyle("-fx-stroke-width:3em; -fx-stroke:linear-gradient(to right, red, green);");
    //line.setStyle("-fx-stroke-width:3em; -fx-stroke:linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green);");

    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption it takes the group's bounds is not correct. In fact, it's taking the line's bound. And here is the problem.

If you go to `com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPrismGraphics` you'll see that for a shape with a gradient, this is how `fill()` is done:

```
void fill(java.awt.Shape shape) {
    if (paintWasProportional) {
        if (nodeBounds != null) {
            g2d.setPaint(toJ2DPaint(paint, nodeBounds));
        } else {
            g2d.setPaint(toJ2DPaint(paint, shape.getBounds2D()));
        }
    }
    g2d.fill(shape);
}
```

The `paintWasProportional` check gave me a hint to approach your problem with another perspective.

Let's start by using a `LinearGradient` object, by code instead of using CSS. Then this will be your starting point:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Group group = new Group();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(group, 200, 350));

    Line line = new Line(100, 50, 100, 300);
    LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0d, 0d, 0d, 1d, true,
      CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop(0,Color.RED),new Stop(1,Color.GREEN));
line.setStrokeWidth(36); // 3em
    line.setStroke(linearGradient);
    group.getChildren().add(line);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

With the expected result (the black line is just for reference):

[image: Gradient 1]

Now, to get the gradient `to right`, let's change the way we create the gradient, using a *non proporcional* one:

```
LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0d, 50d, 0d, 300d,
       false, CycleMethod.REFLECT,new Stop(0,Color.RED), new Stop(1,Color.GREEN));
```

This will have the same result.

And if you want to change the direction, this is what you need:

```
LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(100-18d, 0d, 100+18d, 0d,
 false, CycleMethod.REFLECT,new Stop(0,Color.RED), new Stop(1,Color.GREEN));
```

With this result:

[image: Gradient 2]

Note you could try now to get this done also by CSS.

Comment: Well articulated answer!! Thanks...    I tried to do it using css, but there is no place we can specify proportional attribute's value. For doing that I will have to use px units. Can not do that either as size of my line is variable :(