# JavaFX line fill color

Tags: line, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a line with a different fill and stroke color, something like this:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
Line line = new Line(0,0,100,100);
line.setFill(Color.RED);
line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
line.setStrokeWidth(10);
```

but this gives me just a black line.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with a simple Line or do I have to use another `Shape`? (I would prefer using a line because I have to frequently call the `setStartX`, `setStartY`, ... methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026986/linear-gradients-bounds-computation-takes-parents-bounds-in-account-not-the-n), you'll see that you can only use `setStroke`. Also, a possible approach to generate the same styling is proposed by using a linear gradiant.

This will work (adjust stops at your convenience for more or less black width):

```
Line line = new Line(0,0,100,0);
line.setStrokeWidth(10);
line.setStroke(new LinearGradient(0d, -5d, 0d, 5d, false,
                CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop(0,Color.BLACK), 
                                      new Stop(0.199,Color.BLACK),
                                      new Stop(0.2,Color.RED),
                                      new Stop(0.799,Color.RED),
                                      new Stop(0.8,Color.BLACK)));
```

[image: line gradient]

Note also that since the gradient is not proportional, you need to use rotation to generate not horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of José Pereda is more elegant but I couldn't get the math right to create diagonal lines so as a workaround I simply created two lines, each with a different color:

```
Line stroke = new Line(0, 0, 100, 100);
Line fill = new Line(0, 0, 100, 100);
stroke.setStrokeWidth(10);
fill.setStrokeWidth(8);
stroke.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
fill.setStroke(Color.RED);
pane.addAll(stroke, fill);
```

No math required and I can keep on using the `setStartX`,`setStartY`, ... methods of the lines although I now have double the amount of lines.

Comment: You can just rotate the line, with `line.setRotate(45);` to rotate from its center, or `line.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(45,0,0));` to control the pivot point.