# How to set style color for a line in javafx?

Tags: css, javafx

How to set style color for a line in javafx?

```
 public void setColor(String color) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){ 
          //lines[i].setFill(Color.BLUE);
          //lines[i].setStyle("-fx-Background-color: yellow;");
          //lines[i].setStyle("-fx-color:"+ color);
         //setStyle("-fx-Foreground-color:"+ color);
      }

  }
```

All 4 comments do nothing the lines not colored.

I would be happy if you could help me.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764190/javafx-line-fill-color

Answer (score 16):

Use `-fx-stroke` for coloring lines (using CSS)

```
line.setStyle("-fx-stroke: red;");
```

Or call [setStroke()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setStroke-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-) for coloring lines (using Java API):

```
line.setStroke(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a for loop to get the children of the "lines"array and then using "-fx-stroke:" as ItachiUchiha suggested but adding the color to the string.

Here is the code:

```
public void setColor(String color) {
  for (Line line:lines){ 
      line.setStyle("-fx-stroke:"+ color);
  }
}
```

I hope this helps. If you have any question just ask.